# PHP 5.3 magic_quotes_gpc On but not working

Tags: php, fastcgi, magic-quotes-gpc

I've a problem with `magic_quotes_gpc`. I'm migrating a webserver from an XP machine to a Win2003 one. PHP code is in some cases old, and not really well developed, so I really need to have `magic_quotes_gpc` working.

I'm pretty sure that configurations were made properly, I've also tryed copying old PHP folder and php.ini, but still have the problem. Having `magic_quotes_gpc = On` have the exact behavior of having it `magic_quotes_gpc = Off`.

Tryied with PHP 5.3 but even with the older 5.1 working properly on the old server.

The only difference is that in the new server I use FastCGI.

I'm really in your hands to solve this, I'm really getting crazy!

20140326 - Add code example as per Alvaro suggestion

```
<?
  print $_GET["id"];
  print '<br><br>';
  print $_GET[id];
?>
```

Calling page `./sample.php?id=1`, only this line is displayed (I've errors on):

`PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\simple.php on line 4`

Commenting line 4:

```
<?
  print $_GET["id"];
  print '<br><br>';
  //print $_GET[id];
?>
```

Output is 1 as expected.

Comment: Apart from indirect checks, can you run `phpinfo()` and have a look?

Comment: phpinfo() shows `magic_quotes_gpc On On`

Comment: Then it's on... Have you tried a simple test script? Can you share it with us (code and output)?

Comment: I've added test script as suggested, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test code is totally unrelated to [magic quotes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php) thus I suspect you've misunderstood what the feature does. With magic quotes, you'd call this URL:

```
/test.php?foo=O'Hara
```

... where `test.php` is:

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET);
```

... and get this back:

```
array(1) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(7) "O\'Hara"
}
```

... instead of this:

```
array(1) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(6) "O'Hara"
}
```

However, you are attempting to use a non-existing constant, as here:

```
<?php
define('this_exists', 'yes');
echo this_exists;
echo this_does_not_exist;
```

... and you possibly want that PHP does not warn you about the error:

> PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant this_does_not_exist - assumed 'this_does_not_exist'

So you basically want to fiddle with [error_reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) and omit `E_NOTICE`.

Comment: More to add, Actually `print $_GET[id]` is common mistake done in code by php programmers, As it just throw notice and then convert silently constant id to string 'id', So php finally execute it as print $_GET['id']. He must use $_GET['id'] OR $_GET["id"].

Comment: What's strange is that the same code in the old server is not generating any error, and the output is "correct". I cannot understand why in 2 servers I have different behaviuors.

Comment: Because error reporting is **configurable**. That's why the setting exists in the first place.